# Cant access ICollection data in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I stumbled upon an error when i try to access my ICollection content.
Code as follows:
View

```
foreach (var carInfo in Model)
{
    @carInfo.Id
    @carInfo.Brand
    ......... ect.

    foreach (var rentInfo in carInfo.RentInfo)
    {
       @rentInfo.RentDate
       ....... ect.
    }
}
```

View top:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestApp.Models.Cars>
```

Car Model:

```
public class Cars
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CarPlateNumber { get; set;  }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public int SeatCount { get; set; }
    public string GearBox { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CarRent> RentInfo { get; set; }
}
```

If i remove code:

```
foreach (var rentInfo in carInfo.RentInfo)
        {
           @rentInfo.RentDate
           ....... ect.
        }
```

Everything works fine, the question is why does this aprouch does not work?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the error? Try `@foreach...` and remove @ while accessing variables.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Developer @ before variable is a must in .cshtml file.

Comment: @RobertsKalderauskis it is not a must. It is a must when you open the razor code block. You dont need it if you are inside a structure already flagged with @

Comment: @RobertsKalderauskis: That is not the error. That's just a generalized 500 meaning *something* is wrong. Post the stack trace.

Comment: After looking into stack i found out that the problem is with line {@foreach (var rentInfo in carInfo.RentInfo)}

The stack error:

"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel: Error: An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Asp.ASPV__Views_Shared_Home_cshtml.<ExecuteAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in /Views/Shared/Home.cshtml:line 68"

Answer (score 0):

I did find what was the error in my case. The problem was rather simple, whenever my ICollection returned null from db this error occured. So i did put simple if statement to check wheather reference:

```
carInfo.RentInfo
```

Is not null and only then perform foreach command. Thanks guys for your help.